# If statement not working in Spotfire

Tags: if-statement, calculated-columns, spotfire

I hope you can help I am attempting to use an If statement in Spotfire. What I am trying to achieve is this

I have 13 unique numbers and what I am trying to say is that if column `[GL_ACCOUNT(2)]` = any of these 13 numbers then return me "Not EFPIA" in my new calculated column 'GL Account Filter'

It works up to two numbers but once i increase the amount of numbers the formula will not work.

My Code is below. As always any help is greatly appreciated

```
if([GL_ACCOUNT(2)]="0063304000","0063401000", "0062001000", "Not EFPIA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `TERR` or `JS` or `IronPY` you'll have to explicitly `OR` these together. I think you are trying to do something like the `IN` clause in `TSQL` as [explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) but I'm unaware of that functionality in `Spotfire`.

```
if([GL_ACCOUNT(2)]="0063304000" or 
   [GL_ACCOUNT(2)]="0063401000" or 
   [GL_ACCOUNT(2)]="0062001000", "Not EFPIA")
```

You can also do this with a `CASE` if that's more legible for you.

```
case
   when [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0063304000" then "Not EFPIA"
   when [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0063401000" then "Not EFPIA"
   when [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0062001000" then "Not EFPIA"
   else NULL
end
```

Or with the `OR`....

```
case
   when [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0063304000" OR
        [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0063401000" OR
        [GL_ACCOUNT(2)] = "0062001000" then "Not EFPIA"
   else NULL
end
```

Comment: No worries mate, glad it worked out for you @PhilipConnell

Answer (score 0):

The expression can be used as

```
if([GL_ACCOUNT(2)] in "0063304000","0063401000", "0062001000", "Not EFPIA")
```